# Find the City with highest population in each Country from a List of Countries using Stream API

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have two classes: `Country` and `City`.

Country has the following attributes: `Countrycode`, `Countryname`, `capital`, `population`, `Continent` and a list of type `City`.

City has `countrycode`, `name` and `population` attributes.

I am trying to find the highest populated city of each Country.

I want to use the Stream API.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Main13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<Country> Countries=new ArrayList<Country>();
        
        //Countrycode,Countryname,capital,population,Continent
        
        Country coun1=new Country(1,"Japan","Tokyo",4000000,"Asia");
        Country coun2=new Country(2,"USA","DC",400000000,"America");
        
        
        City c1=new City(1,"Tokyo",100000);
        City c2=new City(1,"Osaka",10000);
        City c3=new City(1,"Nagoya",20000);
        
        City n1=new City(2,"NYC",4000000);
        City n2=new City(2,"LA",1000000);
        
        
        coun1.Cities.add(c1);
        coun1.Cities.add(c2);
        coun1.Cities.add(c3);
        
        coun2.Cities.add(n1);
        coun2.Cities.add(n2);
        
        Countries.add(coun1);
        Countries.add(coun2);
        
        Country Max2=Countries.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Country::getpop)).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
        
        System.out.println(Max2.Countryname);
    }

}

////////////////////////////////////////////
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Country {
    int countrycode;
    String Countryname; 
    String Capital; 
    int Population;
    String Continent; 
    ArrayList<City> Cities=new ArrayList<City>();

    public Country(int code,String n,String c,int p,String con) {
        countrycode=code;
        Countryname=n; 
        Capital=c; 
        Population=p;
        Continent=con;
    }

    public int getpop() {
        return Population;
    }

}
////////////////////////

public class City {

    int CountryCode;
    String name;
    int Population;
    
    
    
    public City(int code,String n,int pop) {
        CountryCode=code;
        name=n;
        Population=pop;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cities does seem to be an ArrayList so a list, not an array, is that correct ?

Comment: Can you share both classes definition, so we can rnu your code ?

Comment: @azro yes Cities is an Arraylist

Comment: Regarding your title that doesn't seem very for you the difference between list and array, you may . I'd suggest some read like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/ If i'm wrong, don't bother to tell me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to do something for each country, you need to loop on the coutries, then apply the logic

```
for (Country c : countries) {
    City max2 = c.cities.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(City::getPopulation))
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
    System.out.println(c.getName() + " " + max2.getName() + " " + max2.getPopulation());
}
```

```
Japan Tokyo 100000
USA NYC 4000000
```

---

Note : java variable naming convention is lowerCamelCase

```
class Country {
    int code;
    String name;
    String capital;
    int population;
    String continent;
    List<City> cities;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find the highest populated city of each Country.

That's how you can create a list of the most populated cities in each country:

```
List<City> largestCities = countries.stream()
    .map(country -> country.getCities().stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(City::getPopulation)))
    .map(Optional::orElseThrow)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
largestCities.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
City{CountryCode=1, name='Tokyo', population=100000}
City{CountryCode=2, name='NYC', population=4000000}
```

[*A link to the Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rBr)

*Important notes:*

- Providing `NoSuchElementException` an argument of `orElseThrow()` doesn't make sense because [parameterless version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) of this method throw `NoSuchElementException` is a case of *empty optional*.
- Adhere to the [*Java Naming Conventions*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). Names of variables and methods should be written in so-called *camel-case* (*mixed case*) and always start with a lower case letter: `cities`, `getCities()`, `countryCode`, `population`, etc.
- Write your code against interfaces not against concrete implementations, use `List` instead of `ArrayList`. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)
- Use access modifiers to encapsulate class-members withing the class. In order to be able to change a state of a particular field you need to introduce a method, avoid accessing the field directly from outside the class (*don't access the field directly - it's not a good practice in Java*):

```
private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();

public void addCity(City city) {
    cities.add(city);
}
```

Comment: Does the function getCities() only return the the List?

Comment: @JohnJavaS It's standard name for a so-called *getter* method (method that allows to access the field). Accessing the field directly is not a good practice in Java.

Comment: Ik but the output didnt work so just wanted to make sure its not from this methode

Comment: @JohnJavaS If you didn't manage to make the code from the answer working, here is a link to [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rBr)